# Capturing "x" seconds of video with Trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

I'm using this to trigger capture video:

```
forge.file.getVideo({source:'camera'}, ...)
```

My question is this: once the user starts recording, how do I set a "maximum recorded length in seconds"?

I'd like to only permit users to record 1 second of video. Is this possible using Trigger.io, or would I have to build a native component for this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a configurable parameter of `getVideo` at the moment - if you wanted to create a native plugin to support this, take a look at [`videoMaximumDuration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) on iOS and [`EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT) on the Android intent.

Or, if you would prefer to wait for this to be available in our file module, get in touch at support@trigger.io to discuss timings!